# Regex split boolean string by boolean operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

Is there a regex to split boolean string by boolean operator but not within quotes

example: `boolean_string = "'larsen and turbo' and fullsta'ck or \"ruby\" and \"ruby or rails\""`

expected output: `['larsen and turbo', and, fullsta'ck, or, ruby, and, ruby or rails]`

Currently trying with below code snippet but unable to escape operators within quotes.
`boolean_string.split(/\b(and|or)\b/)`

How do I escape `and` and `or's` within quotes.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may helps you:

```rb
boolean_string = "'larsen and turbo' and fullsta'ck or \"ruby\" and \"ruby or rails\""
reg = %r{
  (?:                # outer-group to use "|" for multiple matches
    ['"]([^'"]+)['"] # words inside quotes
    |([\w']+)        # other words
  )
}xm

boolean_string.scan(reg).flat_map(&:compact) # => ["larsen and turbo", "and", "fullsta'ck", "or", "ruby", "and", "ruby or rails"]
```